# React Layout with own reducer

Tags: reactjs, layout, redux, react-router, react-redux

I have react-redux application, where I need to inject some state and reducers inside the layout. I have routes -

```
export const createRoutes = (store) => ({
path        : '/',
component   : CoreLayout,
indexRoute  : Index(store),
childRoutes : [
  ....
]
```

And my core layout component needs to be a component, I can`t use it like method, because i got an error. Its invalid -

```
getComponent (nextState, cb) {
require.ensure([], (require) => {
  const Layout= require('./containers/CoreLayoutContainer').default;
  const reducer= require('../../modules/reducer').default;

  injectReducer(store, { key: 'layout', reducer})

  cb(null, Layout)
}, 'SongsList')
```

And my biggest problem its that, if I trying to create layout with container

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
changePlaybackTime: (newTime) => changePlaybackTime(newTime),
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    currentSongId: state.songs.player.currentSongId,
    isPaused : state.songs.player.isPaused,
    isPlaying: state.songs.player.isPlaying,
})


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CoreLayout)
```

Every time in `mapStateToProps` I got state of reducers, which I define in **current** route's `getComponent(nextState, cb)` method. How can I inject own reducers to layout? Thanks.

UPD: Show injectReducer function:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'

export const makeRootReducer = (asyncReducers) => {
   return combineReducers({
      //you can add global reducers here and got it everywhere
      ...asyncReducers
  })
}

 export const injectReducer = (store, { key, reducer }) => {
    if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(store.asyncReducers, key)) return

    store.asyncReducers[key] = reducer
    store.replaceReducer(makeRootReducer(store.asyncReducers))
}
```

Comment: Could you also show your `injectReducer` definition? There is no such function in redux core API

Comment: Yes, with pleasure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if anybody will enforce this question - there is no way to inject dynamyc reducer inside the layout, but if you need to have any reducer for entire lifecycle of the app you can inject that reducer globally.